# ASP.NET POST Form Data is lost after authentication on Identityserver

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, identityserver4

I have an asp.net mvc project using identityserver4 implicit flow as authentication method. I'm using Reference tokens instead of JWT, so that the MVC client application has to re-authorize the token every one in a while on the server.

The problem I'm facing is when I'm submitting a form on the client and on submit it goes to the authentication endpoint (right before the actual submit).
After the authentication, I get sent back to my URL, but as a GET. Thus the POST data is lost and I have to fill in the form again.

What I'm trying to do now is keeping track of the form data before redirecting to identityserver4 and adjusting the response to make it a POST again:

The method below makes it possible to adjust the context (make it a POST request and add the correct data), but it still redirects back as a GET.

```
private Dictionary<string, IOwinRequest> tempRequests = new Dictionary<string, IOwinRequest>();

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    [removed for brevity...]

    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
    {
        RedirectToIdentityProvider = async (context) =>
        {
            if (context.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication && context.Request.Method == HttpMethods.Post)
            {
                // When it's a POST request, save the request and keep track of it using a Guid reference
                string requestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var stateQueryString = context.ProtocolMessage.State.Split('=');
                var protectedState = stateQueryString[1];
                var state = context.Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(protectedState);
                state.Dictionary.Add("OidcPostRedirectRequestId", requestId);
                tempRequests.Add(requestId, context.Request);
                context.ProtocolMessage.State = $"{stateQueryString[0]}={context.Options.StateDataFormat.Protect(state)}";
            }
        },
        SecurityTokenValidated = context =>
        {
            var stateQueryString = context.ProtocolMessage.State.Split('=');
            var protectedState = stateQueryString[1];
            var state = context.Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(protectedState);
            if (state.Dictionary.ContainsKey("OidcPostRedirectRequestId"))
            {
                // Reference found, update request and add form data back to it
                state.Dictionary.TryGetValue("OidcPostRedirectRequestId", out string requestId);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestId))
                {
                    state.Dictionary.Remove("OidcPostRedirectRequestId");
                    context.ProtocolMessage.State = $"{stateQueryString[0]}={context.Options.StateDataFormat.Protect(state)}";
                    tempRequests.TryGetValue(requestId, out IOwinRequest data);
                    if (data != null)
                    {
                        tempRequests.Remove(requestId);
                        context.Request.Body = data.Body;
                        context.Request.ContentType = data.ContentType;
                        context.Request.Method = data.Method;
                        context.Request.Headers.Clear();
                        foreach (var header in data.Headers)
                        {
                            context.Request.Headers.Add(header);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
});
```

I'm I going about this this wrong way? How can I make the redirect from Identityserver4 back to the client as a POST if necessary?

Thanks in advance.

## -- UPDATE 17/07

Since it didn't work out, I'm trying to create a custom redirect handler by extending the OidcAuthorization middleware.

```
public static class OidcAuthenticationExtensions
{
    public static readonly string OidcPostRedirectKey = "OidcPostRedirectRequestId";
    public static Dictionary<string, IOwinRequest> PostRedirectRequests = new Dictionary<string, IOwinRequest>();
    public static IAppBuilder UseKpcOidcAuthentication(this IAppBuilder app, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions options)
    {
        if (app == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("app");
        }

        if (options == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("openIdConnectOptions");
        }

        return app.Use(typeof(CustomAuthMiddleware), app, options);
    }
}

public class CustomOIDCAuthenticationHandler : OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler
{
    public CustomOIDCAuthenticationHandler(ILogger logger)
        : base(logger) { }

    public override Task<bool> InvokeAsync()
    {
        return InvokeReplyPathAsync();
    }

    private async Task<bool> InvokeReplyPathAsync()
    {
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = await AuthenticateAsync();

        if (ticket != null)
        {
            if (ticket.Properties.Dictionary.TryGetValue("HandledResponse", out string value) && value == "true")
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (ticket.Identity != null)
            {
                Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(ticket.Properties, ticket.Identity);
            }
            // Redirect back to the original secured resource, if any.
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ticket.Properties.RedirectUri))
            {
                Response.Redirect($"/Helper/RedirectHandler?redirectUrl={ticket.Properties.RedirectUri}");
                //Response.Redirect(ticket.Properties.RedirectUri);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class CustomAuthMiddleware : OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public CustomAuthMiddleware(OwinMiddleware nextMiddleware, IAppBuilder app, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions authOptions)
        : base(nextMiddleware, app, authOptions)
    {
        _logger = app.CreateLogger<CustomAuthMiddleware>();
    }

    protected override AuthenticationHandler<OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> CreateHandler()
    {
        return new CustomOIDCAuthenticationHandler(_logger);
    }
}
```

```
public async Task<ActionResult> RedirectHandler(string redirectUrl)
{
    var claim = (((ClaimsPrincipal)User).FindFirst(OidcAuthenticationExtensions.OidcPostRedirectKey));
    if (claim != null)
    {
        var requestId = claim.Value;
        OidcAuthenticationExtensions.PostRedirectRequests.TryGetValue(requestId, out IOwinRequest data);
        if (data != null)
        {
            OidcAuthenticationExtensions.PostRedirectRequests.Remove(requestId);
            // TODO: post to action
            IFormCollection formData = await data.ReadFormAsync();
            //FormData is correct, but I need to be able to post it...
        }
    }
    return Redirect(redirectUrl);
}
```

Using this, I can just Redirect to the URL if the request was just a GET. When it's a POST though, I'd like to post the data. Any ideas on how to best achieve this?

Comment: Hey, I had an instance where i seperated identity server from my client side application (different project, different database), although i wanted to keep record of some user data in my client side application. I (ab)used the data set to the principal and implemented an auto post when receiving the GET request from identity server, the view returned from that GET request contain nothing but hidden elements and a small piece of javascript code to auto submit the page after it loaded. Dunno if this helps your question directly.

Comment: That's the reason we use Reference tokens instead of JWT. Because these reference tokens are not self-contained, every 5 minutes (when the IdentityToken invalidates) the client does a request to the authentication endpoint where it rebuilds the userdata and redirects back to the client where we can access the new data. The problem is that this redirect is always a GET. So when a POST-action happens and the IdentityToken is invalid, it goes to the identityserver, which redirects back to the client, but without the POST-data.

Comment: Okay great thnx for the clarification, I understand your code now and see what you are trying to accomplish. You are trying to re-set your data after the token is validated based on the dictionary. Unfortunately i have no direct answer for you. One thing im guessing here is that Func (SecurityTokenValidated) is issued after the system determined where to redirect to (so setting the correct method on request wont affect the actual redirect), i saw that OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications has other funcs which might be helpfull :)

Comment: Thank you for your response! The Func is called after a new IdentityToken is generated. You are right about what I'm trying to accomplish, unfortunately though I haven't found any useful OIDC func to help me with it.

Comment: Hey, have you tried manipulating the response object instead or request object on the context?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I have tried, but to no avail. What I'm trying now is creating a custom Redirect Handler (by extending the OIDC middleware). I still haven't figured out how I can 'redirect' to a post action though.

Comment: I have updated my original question with what I'm trying to achieve now.

Comment: well a quick way out would be use the HttpClientFactory for creating an Http request. But I have the feeling something is missing here. are you extending this one [OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware](https://github.com/c4net/katanaproject/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware.cs)?

Comment: Yes, and in there I'm overriding the [OpenidConnectAuthenticationHandler](https://github.com/c4net/katanaproject/blob/df66bf44ffc4b5de0ec9a837f4a470614a9c68bf/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/OpenidConnectAuthenticationHandler.cs) function **InvokeAsync()**. I'm telling this function to always redirect to the RedirectHandler. I have added the code to my original question.

Comment: Ow yes I see now, and the redirect uri from the authentication ticket properties (ticket.Properties.RedirectUri) is set correctly?

Comment: Yes, it is set to my original POST request URI.

Comment: Okay so we can asume that the properties on the authenication ticket have been constructed correctly. I have been trying to back trace when Reponse.Redirect performs an actual HTTP-request but without success at the moment (altough its realy fascinating). The issue you have right now is the the Redirect Action result isnt able to receive an instance of your form data. Have you tried using an HTTPClient?

Comment: Fascinating indeed, but time consuming... And weirdly enough not a lot of similar problems when searching for answers (I mean, we can't be the only ones facing this problem) :p
Actually I'm trying to redirect the user back to the original POST request. I could use an HttpClient to post the data, but then I wouldn't be able to redirect the user back the the original form he filled out and tried to submit, am I right?

Comment: Yes i understand what you mean, and thats why i have the feeling something obvious is missing here. Just to be sure you are talking about redirecting him back to the GET method which builds the form in case the POST fails?

Comment: If the POST fails, I wan't to redirect him back to the original view, but with the ModelState errors from the POST (so the user can see what is wrong with the form)

Comment: Yeah this should be handled by the post method itself once you hit it. Anyway apparently we are thinking in the wrong direction according the @Nenad :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having the same problem, I got it solved by overriding the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler`.

What I did first was implement my own custom `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware`, which implements my custom `AuthenticationHandler`.
By default, the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler` will always redirect by returning a
302 response code, thus resulting in loss of POST data.

```
public static class OidcAuthenticationExtensions
{
    public static readonly string OidcPostRedirectKey = "OidcPostRedirectRequestId";
    public static Dictionary<string, HttpContext> PostRedirectRequests = new Dictionary<string, HttpContext>();
    public static IAppBuilder UseKpcOidcAuthentication(this IAppBuilder app, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions options)
    {
        if (app == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("app");
        }

        if (options == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("openIdConnectOptions");
        }

        return app.Use(typeof(CustomAuthMiddleware), app, options);
    }
}

public class CustomOIDCAuthenticationHandler : OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler
{
    public CustomOIDCAuthenticationHandler(ILogger logger)
        : base(logger) { }

    public override Task<bool> InvokeAsync()
    {
        return InvokeReplyPathAsync();
    }

    private async Task<bool> InvokeReplyPathAsync()
    {
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = await AuthenticateAsync();

        if (ticket != null)
        {
            if (ticket.Properties.Dictionary.TryGetValue("HandledResponse", out string value) && value == "true")
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (ticket.Identity != null)
            {
                Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(ticket.Properties, ticket.Identity);
            }
            // Redirect back to the original secured resource, if any.
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ticket.Properties.RedirectUri))
            {
                var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).FindFirst(OidcAuthenticationExtensions.OidcPostRedirectKey);
                if (claim != null)
                {
                    var requestId = claim.Value;
                    OidcAuthenticationExtensions.PostRedirectRequests.TryGetValue(requestId, out HttpContext data);
                    if (data != null)
                    {
                        WebExtensions.RedirectWithData(data.Request, data.Request.RawUrl);
                    }
                    ((ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).RemoveClaim(claim);
                    OidcAuthenticationExtensions.PostRedirectRequests.Remove(requestId);
                    if (data == null)
                    {
                        Response.Redirect(ticket.Properties.RedirectUri);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect(ticket.Properties.RedirectUri);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class CustomAuthMiddleware : OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public CustomAuthMiddleware(OwinMiddleware nextMiddleware, IAppBuilder app, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions authOptions)
        : base(nextMiddleware, app, authOptions)
    {
        _logger = app.CreateLogger<CustomAuthMiddleware>();
    }

    protected override AuthenticationHandler<OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> CreateHandler()
    {
        return new CustomOIDCAuthenticationHandler(_logger);
    }
}
```

So if there is a `Post` action to perform, the middleware will recreate the request using following function:

```
public static class WebExtensions
    {
        public static void RedirectWithData(HttpRequest request, string url)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            s.Append("<html>");
            s.AppendFormat("<body onload='document.forms[\"form\"].submit()'>");
            s.AppendFormat("<form name='form' action='{0}' method='post'>", url);
            foreach (string key in request.Form)
            {
                s.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='{0}' value='{1}' />", key, request.Form[key]);
            }
            s.Append("</form></body></html>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(s.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

By implementing this, we can initialze the middleware in the `Startup` class as following:

```
app.UseKpcOidcAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    [Removed for brevity...]
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
    {
        RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
        {
            if (context.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication && context.Request.Method == HttpMethods.Post)
            {
                // When it's a POST request, save the request and keep track of it using a Guid reference
                // Also add the requestId to the request state, so we can retrieve it after authentication on the IdentityServer
                string requestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var stateQueryString = context.ProtocolMessage.State.Split('=');
                var protectedState = stateQueryString[1];
                var state = context.Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(protectedState);
                state.Dictionary.Add(OidcAuthenticationExtensions.OidcPostRedirectKey, requestId);
                OidcAuthenticationExtensions.PostRedirectRequests.Add(requestId, System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
                context.ProtocolMessage.State = $"{stateQueryString[0]}={context.Options.StateDataFormat.Protect(state)}";
            }
            
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        },
        SecurityTokenValidated = context =>
        {
            // Retrieve possible requestId from the state
            var stateQueryString = context.ProtocolMessage.State.Split('=');
            var protectedState = stateQueryString[1];
            var state = context.Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(protectedState);
            if (state.Dictionary.ContainsKey(OidcAuthenticationExtensions.OidcPostRedirectKey))
            {
                // Reference found, update request and add form data back to it
                state.Dictionary.TryGetValue(OidcAuthenticationExtensions.OidcPostRedirectKey, out string requestId);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestId))
                {
                    state.Dictionary.Remove(OidcAuthenticationExtensions.OidcPostRedirectKey);
                    context.ProtocolMessage.State = $"{stateQueryString[0]}={context.Options.StateDataFormat.Protect(state)}";
                    // Temporarily add the request id to the user claims, so it can be read in the redirect handler
                    user.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(OidcAuthenticationExtensions.OidcPostRedirectKey, requestId));
                }
            }
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
});
```

So the flow we get now is:

1. User submits a form on the client (which has an invalidated identity token)
2. The client performs a redirect the the `/connect/authorize` endpoint to get a new token. Before the actual redirect, we store the initial `HttpContext` in memory referenced by a `Guid`. We also add this `Guid` to the `request state`. (See `RedirectToIdentityProvider` event)
3. IdentityServer issues a new `IdenityToken` and redirects back to the client
4. `SecurityTokenValidated` got triggered. We retrieve the reference `Guid` from the `request` and temporarily add it to the `User Claims`.
5. The `AuthenticationMiddleware` invokes a redirect to the original `Uri`. We check if the user has a `Claim` referencing an original `POST Request`. If so, we will manually trigger the `Post`using the `RedirectWithData` function; otherwise just redirect using 302.

Answer (score 1):

Sending user's input data to different (authentication) servers in order to preserve it is a wrong direction to go in this case.

OpenID Connect protocol is used for interoperability and common scenario is to use 3rd party authentication servers (eg. Google, Facebook). You wouldn't expect their servers to preserve any random data sent from the client during login process. Even with your own server, it's bad idea to just "extended" the protocol. There is potential privacy issue there as well.

Preserving form input data should be handled on the application side. On the client side would probably be simpler, saving form input data to `localStorage`, cookie, etc... Or on the server side, saving session-state just before GET redirect to OIDC server happens.

This way you don't interfere with OpenID Connect protocol and application is responsible preserve its own data.

Comment: Okay you make a good point there. Still, even if I'm able to preserve the form input data, how will the OIDC middleware know it has to actually submit the form (because the end-user initially pressed submit), and not just redirect back to it?

Comment: In handler `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider`  you can inspect request that triggered redirect, part of the input parameter `RedirectContext` (eg. `ctx.Request`). On the way back from authentication server, I would handle restoring of data on the application's MVC controller level (or filter), not in OIDS middleware redirect handler.

Comment: That's what I initially tried; in handler `OnSecurityTokenValidated` I tried re-setting the context to the original request (as you can see in my original question). Or is this not the place to do the restoring?

Comment: First, "converting" GET to POST halfway through the pipeline also seem to me very wrong thing to do. I would restore the data on the MVC controller level, when controller receives the actual GET request. Also storing of the request data has to be session based. Co-relatable with user who issued request. I don't see how  request ID alone can be sufficient for this.